# VMWare to KVM migration using virt-v2v

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization

I have 2 files that need converting -

vmdk to qcow2, done with `qemu-img convert -f vmdk foo.vmdk -O qcow2 foo.qcow2`

vmx to xml, trying to do with `virt-v2v -i vmx foo.vmx -o disk -os /tmp/test` and get the xml from there, however the following error is thrown:

```
virt-v2v: error: output format should be ‘raw’ or ‘qcow2’.

Use the ‘-of <format>’ option to select a different output format for
the converted guest.

Other output formats are not supported at the moment, although might be
considered in future.

If reporting bugs, run virt-v2v with debugging enabled and include the
complete output:

  virt-v2v -v -x [...]
```

any pointers?

Comment: I would try doing what it advised you to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use virt-convert, for example

```
virt-convert foo.vmx --disk-format qcow2 --destination /tmp/test
```